# How to disable a text area?

Tags: jquery, textarea

How to disable a textarea which is dynamically added to the HTML?

HTML:

```
<div class="ss_datesel_inp_cont">
    <div class="ss_datesel_inp_right_corner">
    </div>
    <input autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

This is what I tried:

```
   $('.ss_datesel_inp_cont:textarea').prop("disabled", true);
   $('.ss_datesel_inp_cont:input').prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: What version of jquery are you using ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I don't see a textarea element in the code you posted? Based on the markup you have, you would disable the input by:

```
$('.ss_datesel_inp_cont input').prop('disabled', true);
```

The reason your code isn't working is simply because the selector is wrong. The input is a descendant of `.ss_datesel_inp_cont` and therefore you need to indicate that with a space between `.ss_datesel_inp_cont` and `input`. The input is also a direct child, so alternatively you could use the direct child token `>` as in `$('.ss_datesel_inp_cont > input')`.

Answer (score 11):

To change the disabled property you should use the .prop() function.

```
$("textarea").prop('disabled', true);
$("textarea").prop('disabled', false);
```

*Note: For jQuery 1.6+*

Comment: This works, but if the person knows the ID selector, would that not by the fastest way in which jquery operations works?  e.g. $("#mytextareaID").prop('disabled', true);

Comment: @TomStickel I added the code in a general sense. If you know the element Id, using it would be more proper and safer. I don't think performance would be much of concern in either case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried,

```
$('.ss_datesel_inp_cont:textarea').attr("disabled", true);
```

`prop` only works for jQuery 1.6 or later.

Comment: I'm trying to add a class just to see if it's working but I can't even do that.

Comment: It may be that jQuery is not initialized, have you looked at the console to see if there are any errors ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
$('.ss_datesel_inp_cont:textarea').prop("disabled", "disabled");
```

or

```
$('.ss_datesel_inp_cont textarea').prop("disabled", "disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

`$('.ss_datesel_inp_cont input').attr('disabled','disabled');`

Your `input` is within the `div`, so you can select it in the same way as you select with css, by a space.

It is a child of the `div`, so you could also do this:

`.ss_datesel_inp_cont > input`

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/UpHsA/