# Edit content onclick and submit to database PHP

Tags: html, forms, button, submit, edit

I am trying to submit a textarea form to the database. In the textarea, there should be a standard "PLease enter..." then when logged in user press the "Edit" button at the side of the form, it should make the textarea to be editable. After which, it should allow the user to submit the content into the database.

I am unable to edit the content as it auto-submit the form without clicking the submit button.

The following are the codes that i have done so far:

```
<div id="review">
<script>
        $('#edit').click(function(){
        $('#editable').removeAttr('readonly');
        $(this).text('submit');
        });
        </script>
<form action="" method="post">

        <textarea cols="50" rows="6" id='editable' readonly>Please post...!</textarea>
        <button id='edit'>Edit</button>

        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="save" onclick="return confirm('Is the form filled out correctly?')"/> 

        </form>     
    </div>
```

Comment: Try this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694694/how-to-disable-a-text-area

Comment: Please see my amended answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the $(this).text('submit');

Basically you're telling the textarea to become editable and then instantly submit the form after that.

Also, your listener might be called before that element is loaded in to the DOM. Place the function in a $(document).ready function. If that doesn't work, try the bellow.

Change your button to the following

```
<div id='edit' onclick="enableText()">Edit</div>
```

and add this script to your page

```
function enableText(){
    document.getElementById("editable").disabled = false;
};
```

Comment: Hi @Gezzasa, i have tried that but it does not work either. The code is used to change the edit button to submit button.